# Vuejs Display running balance

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

So I have a request that fetch the Billed and Payed and i want to make a table with running balance

this is my current fetched data

```
+--------------+------------+----------+
| Date Created |    Billed  |  Payed   |
+--------------+------------+----------+
| 2022-01-01    |     1000   |   0      |
| 2022-01-02    |       0    |   100    |
| 2022-02-01    |     2000   |   0      |
| 2022-02-02    |     0      |   2000   |
| 2022-03-01    |     3000   |   0      |
| 2022-03-02    |      0     |   3000   |
+--------------+------------+----------+
```

I want to make a table like this, that displays running balance

```
    +--------------+------------+----------+----------+
    | Date Created |    Billed  |  Payed   |  Balance |
    +--------------+------------+----------+----------+
    | 2022-01-01    |     1000   |   0      |   1000   |
    | 2022-01-02    |       0    |   100    |    900   |
    | 2022-02-01    |     2000   |   0      |   2900   |
    | 2022-02-02    |     0      |   2000   |    900   |
    | 2022-03-01    |     3000   |   0      |   3900   |
    | 2022-03-02    |      0     |   3500   |    400   |
    +--------------+------------+----------+----------+
```

what have i tried right now is

```
 remainingBalance: function () {
                var tempBalance = this.balance
                return this.collection.map(function(transaction) {
                        tempBalance += (transaction.billed)
                        return parseFloat( tempBalance).toFixed(2)
    
                },0);
                // [900.00, 750.00, 635.00]
            },

<tr v-for="transaction in transactions">
  <td>{{ transaction.id }}</td>
  <td>{{ transaction.billed}}</td>
  <td>{{ transaction.payed}}</td>
  <td>{{ remainingBalance[index] }}</td>
</tr>
```

but it only displays same the starting balance
the value of Payed is always 0 if there is a billed and its vice versa.
there is no row with value on both Billed and Payed.

im looking for either from Vuejs or laravel side when fetching the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by iterating the transactions array and do the calculation on `payed` and `billed` data to update the `balance`. I just created a working demo for you. You can give a try **:**

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    transactions: [{
      id: 1,
      billed: 1000,
      payed: 0
    }, {
      id: 2,
      billed: 0,
      payed: 100
    }, {
      id: 3,
      billed: 2000,
      payed: 0
    }, {
      id: 4,
      billed: 0,
      payed: 2000
    }, {
      id: 5,
      billed: 3000,
      payed: 0
    }, {
      id: 6,
      billed: 0,
      payed: 3500
    }]
  },
  mounted() {
    this.transactions = this.transactions.map((obj, index) => {
      if (obj.id === 1) {
        obj.balance = obj.billed - obj.payed
      } else {
        obj.balance = (!obj.billed && obj.payed)
          ? this.transactions[index - 1].balance - obj.payed
        : obj.billed + this.transactions[index - 1].balance
      }
      return obj;
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <table class="table table-borderd table-striped">
    <thead>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Billed</th>
      <th>Payed</th>
      <th>Balance</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="transaction in transactions">
        <td>{{ transaction.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ transaction.billed }}</td>
        <td>{{ transaction.payed }}</td>
        <td>{{ transaction.balance }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```